# React: What is the best way to block an invalid session from accessing page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, axios, react-router-dom

I am using react-router-dom to handle routes. I am making a simple login page where you login, session gets generated and redirects to home page.

I want to have a check on my home page to say if the user doesn't have a valid session, throw them back to the login page ("/"). I have been at this for hours and my problem is, axios is async so I haven't found a way to not load the page till this check is done, and the solution I have made shows the page for a split second while this call to my API is being made.

What is the standard way of doing this? My method is below:

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import Login from './Login';
import Home from './Home';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios'

export class App extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
         homeRoute: <Route path="/home" component={Home}></Route>
    }
}

getAuthorisedAPI() {
    axios.get("http://localhost:8080/validateSession")
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data.Success)
        if(!response.data.Success) {
            this.setState({
                homeRoute: <Route path="/home" component={Home}><Redirect to="/" /></Route>
            })
        }
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    })
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.getAuthorisedAPI()
}


render() {
    axios.defaults.withCredentials = true
    return (
        <>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
            {
                this.state.homeRoute
            }
        </>
    )
}
}

export default App
```

If there was a way axios could do a non async call so the page load waits for this response then the below would be ideal..

```
const isValid = true
        return (
            <>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
                <Route path="/home" component={Home}>
                    {
                        !isValid && <Redirect to="/" />
                    }
                </Route>
            </>
        )
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on client side, I'd recommend to split your app in two. The `<AuthenticatedApp />` and the `<UnauthenticatedApp />`. You can read more about this on https://kentcdodds.com/blog/authentication-in-react-applications.

The other option is to use `async/await`.

```
async getAuthorisedAPI() {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:8080/validateSession");
        console.log(response.data.Success)
        if(!response.data.Success) {
            this.setState({
                homeRoute: <Route path="/home" component={Home}><Redirect to="/" /></Route>
            })
        }
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

async componentDidMount() {
    await this.getAuthorisedAPI()
}
```

Comment: I will read up about the app split into two, cheers. I tried your recommendation of adding the await to componentDidMount and getAuthorisedAPI methods, but it doesn't wait for some reason. I added a 5 second sleep in my API to test and it loads the home page, then 5 seconds later redirects to the login page

Comment: [Here is an example of this](https://gyazo.com/cc468e44b3575ad08df2c605b8cc4cb4)